# Why does TCP connection termination require 4 steps?

Tags: networking, tcp

So basically, I was asked this question for an interview. The question was:

Why does TCP connection termination require 4 steps?

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46212623/why-tcp-connect-termination-need-4-way-handshake#) I know that, FIN and ACK need to be sent by both sides to complete termination, but another follow up question I couldn't answer was that why does the server have to send 2 messages ( each with only the FIN and ACK bit set respectively).

Why can't it be done together?

Comment: A FIN from one side is simply telling the other side that it is done sending, but it is still willing to listen. That other side ACKs that. When the other side is through sending, then it will send a FIN telling the first side that it is now finished sending, and the first side ACKs that. If one side is done both sending and listening, it sends a RST to immediately  close the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why can't it be done together?

It can be done together and this is actually the common case in practice, i.e.

```
-> FIN
<- FIN, ACK to FIN
-> ACK to FIN
```

But it can also be done separately especially if the peer does not shutdown immediately but still sends data:

```
-> FIN
<- DATA, ACK to FIN
.... <- more DATA (+ again ACK to FIN)
<- FIN (+ again ACK to FIN)
-> ACK to FIN
```

Answer (score 0):

Close is an operation meaning "I have no more data to send." refer to [RFC793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.5).

```
         TCP A                                                TCP B
  1.     ESTABLISHED                                          ESTABLISHED

  2.     (Close)
         FIN-WAIT-1  --> <SEQ=100><ACK=300><CTL=FIN,ACK>  --> CLOSE-WAIT

  3.     FIN-WAIT-2  <-- <SEQ=300><ACK=101><CTL=ACK>      <-- CLOSE-WAIT

  4.                                                          (Close)
         TIME-WAIT   <-- <SEQ=300><ACK=101><CTL=FIN,ACK>  <-- LAST-ACK

  5.     TIME-WAIT   --> <SEQ=101><ACK=301><CTL=ACK>      --> CLOSED

  6.     (2 MSL)
         CLOSED
```

So you can see the client already had no data to send when step2, but the server had not the data to send until step4. The server needs another FIN to tell the client "I have no data to send". That's why it can't work just like TCP connection by 3 steps.